# Can I use setAttribute to change the text inside the text node?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can use nodeValue to change the text inside the text like
`element.firstChild.nodeValue = text`
 but can I use setAttribute to do the same thing?

**HTML :**

```
<p id="description">Some text here.</p>
```

**JS :**

```
var description = document.getElementById("description");
description.setAttribute(nodeValue, text);
```

It doesn't work. Does it means that "nodeValue" is not an attribute of an element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `setAttribute` does, well, set an attribute. It doesn't set contents.

However, you can use CSS to display an attribute as if it were content.

```js
var description = document.getElementById("description");
description.setAttribute('data-content', 'Updated text');
```

```css
#description::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<p id="description" data-content="Some text here."></p>
```

This should only be used for styling purposes, not to insert real content.

Answer (score 4):

You want to set node content here and not node attribute so you could use **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** instead :

```
// Set the text content:
description.textContent = text;
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var description = document.getElementById("description");
var text = 'New text';

description.textContent = text;
```

```html
<p id="description">Some text here.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot. `setAttribute` is used to manipulate HTML element attributes.

For example, if you wanted to update a button to be disabled you would do something like:

```
var button = document.querySelector('my-button');
button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To change the text you should use `textContent`:

```
var description = document.getElementById("description");
description.textContent = 'New text here.';
```

Comment: `description.textContent = 'New text here.';`